# How to change font size of a single record item in Graphviz

Tags: graphviz, statechart

I'm trying to create a state chart from Graphviz of type record. Please check the reference [here](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20lamp%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bshape%3Dpoint%2Clabel%3D%22%22%5DENTRY%0A%20%20%20%20node%20%5Bstyle%3Drounded%20shape%3Drecord%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20ON%20%5Blabel%3D%22%7BOn%7C%20Some%20code%20here%7D%22%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20OFF%20%5Blabel%3D%22%7BOff%7C%20Some%20code%20here%7D%22%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20ENTRY%20-%3E%20ON%5Blabel%3D%22Initialization%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20ON%20-%3E%20OFF%5Blabel%3D%22%7Ctoggle%7C%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20OFF%20-%3E%20ON%5Blabel%3D%22%7Ctoggle%7C%22%5D%0A%7D).

So here is the basic code:

```
digraph lamp {
  node [shape=point,label=""]ENTRY
  node [style=rounded shape=record ]

  ON [label="{On| Some code here}"];
  OFF [label="{Off| Some code here}"];

  ENTRY -> ON[label="Initialization"]
  ON -> OFF[label="|toggle|"]
  OFF -> ON[label="|toggle|"]
}
```

In above code, I need to add some code below the state name like **On** and **Off** where I put the line **Some code here**. Since there will be a code and it can be any number of lines, I like to change the font size of this single record block where I will put the code (Not the state name record).

So in this line of code:

> ON [label="{On| Some code here}"];

I like to change the font size of *Some code here* only not of *On*.

So, How can I get the control to independently change styling like font size or font name etc of the entered code here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use html-like text, without building tables. (https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html).  Like so:

```
digraph lamp {
  node [shape=point,label=""]ENTRY
  node [style=rounded shape=record ]

  ON [label=<{<FONT COLOR="RED" POINT-SIZE="24.0">On</FONT>|<FONT COLOR="darkgreen" POINT-SIZE="10.0"> Some code here</FONT>}>];
  OFF [label=<{<FONT COLOR="black" POINT-SIZE="24.0">Off</FONT>|<FONT COLOR="darkred" POINT-SIZE="10.0"> Some code here</FONT>}>];

  ENTRY -> ON[label="Initialization"]
  ON -> OFF[label="  |toggle|  "]
  OFF -> ON[label="  |toggle|  "]
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Hi @sroush, thanks for the answer. Facing one more issue regarding graphviz. Hope you can help with this one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68953216/hierarchical-state-machine-with-graphviz