# Hierarchical State Machine with Graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot, statechart

I'm trying to make a State diagram of the Vendor Machine with the help of Graphviz.

I want a outcome close to [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH2du.png).

It consists of nested State Machines as well. Here is what I have done so far in Graphviz. Please find the online demo [here](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20vendorMachine%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20compound%3Dtrue%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20Entry%5Bshape%3D%22point%22%20label%3D%22%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20subgraph%20cluster_cancel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%20%3D%20%22Cancel%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%20%3D%20rounded%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20C0%20%5Blabel%20%3D%20%3C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctable%20cellborder%3D%220%22%20style%3D%22rounded%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3EC0%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chr%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3E%20margin%3D0%20shape%3Dnone%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20C25%20%5Blabel%20%3D%20%3C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctable%20cellborder%3D%220%22%20style%3D%22rounded%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3EC25%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chr%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3E%20margin%3D0%20shape%3Dnone%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20C50%20%5Blabel%20%3D%20%3C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctable%20cellborder%3D%220%22%20style%3D%22rounded%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3EC50%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chr%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3E%20margin%3D0%20shape%3Dnone%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20C75%20%5Blabel%20%3D%20%3C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctable%20cellborder%3D%220%22%20style%3D%22rounded%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3EC75%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chr%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3E%20margin%3D0%20shape%3Dnone%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20subgraph%20cluster_DispenseC100Drink%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%20%3D%20%22DispenseC100Drink%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%20%3D%20rounded%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20C100%20%5Blabel%20%3D%20%3C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctable%20cellborder%3D%220%22%20style%3D%22rounded%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3EC100%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chr%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3E%20margin%3D0%20shape%3Dnone%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20subgraph%20cluster_DispenseC125Drink%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%20%3D%20%22DispenseC125Drink%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20style%20%3D%20rounded%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20C125%20%5Blabel%20%3D%20%3C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctable%20cellborder%3D%220%22%20style%3D%22rounded%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3EC125%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chr%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3E%20margin%3D0%20shape%3Dnone%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20C150%20%5Blabel%20%3D%20%3C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctable%20cellborder%3D%220%22%20style%3D%22rounded%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3EC150%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chr%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3E%20margin%3D0%20shape%3Dnone%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20C175%20%5Blabel%20%3D%20%3C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctable%20cellborder%3D%220%22%20style%3D%22rounded%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3EC175%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chr%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3E%20margin%3D0%20shape%3Dnone%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20C200%20%5Blabel%20%3D%20%3C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctable%20cellborder%3D%220%22%20style%3D%22rounded%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3EC200%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chr%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3E%20margin%3D0%20shape%3Dnone%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20Entry%20-%3E%20C0%0A%20%20%20%20C0%20-%3E%20C25%5Blabel%3D%22%20Add%5Cn%240.25%20%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20C0%20-%3E%20C50%5Blabel%3D%22%20Add%5Cn%240.50%20%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20C25%20-%3E%20C50%5Blabel%3D%22%20Add%5Cn%240.25%20%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20C25%20-%3E%20C75%5Blabel%3D%22%20Add%5Cn%240.50%20%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20C50%20-%3E%20C75%5Blabel%3D%22%20Add%5Cn%240.25%20%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20C50%20-%3E%20C100%5Blabel%3D%22%20Add%5Cn%240.50%20%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20C100%20-%3E%20C0%5Blabel%3D%22%20Dispense%5Cn%20%241.00%20Drink%20%22%20ltail%3D%22cluster_DispenseC100Drink%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20C75%20-%3E%20C100%5Blabel%3D%22%20Add%5Cn%240.25%20%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20C75%20-%3E%20C125%5Blabel%3D%22%20Add%5Cn%240.50%20%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20C100%20-%3E%20C125%5Blabel%3D%22%20Add%5Cn%240.25%20%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20C100%20-%3E%20C150%5Blabel%3D%22%20Add%5Cn%240.50%20%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20C125%20-%3E%20C150%5Blabel%3D%22%20Add%5Cn%240.25%20%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20C125%20-%3E%20C175%5Blabel%3D%22%20Add%5Cn%240.50%20%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20C125%20-%3E%20C0%5Blabel%3D%22%20Dispense%5Cn%20%241.25%20Drink%20%22%20%20ltail%3D%22cluster_DispenseC125Drink%22%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20C150%20-%3E%20C175%5Blabel%3D%22%20Add%5Cn%240.25%20%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20C150%20-%3E%20C200%5Blabel%3D%22%20Add%5Cn%240.50%20%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20C175%20-%3E%20C200%5Blabel%3D%22%20Add%5Cn%240.25%20%22%5D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20C200%20-%3E%20C0%5Blabel%3D%22%20Dispense%5Cn%20%242.00%20Drink%20%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%7D).

```
digraph vendorMachine {
compound=true

Entry[shape="point" label=""]

subgraph cluster_cancel {
    label = "Cancel"
    style = rounded

    C0 [label = <
        <table cellborder="0" style="rounded">
            <tr><td>C0</td></tr>
            <hr/>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
        </table>
    > margin=0 shape=none]
    
    C25 [label = <
        <table cellborder="0" style="rounded">
            <tr><td>C25</td></tr>
            <hr/>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
        </table>
    > margin=0 shape=none]

    C50 [label = <
        <table cellborder="0" style="rounded">
            <tr><td>C50</td></tr>
            <hr/>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
        </table>
    > margin=0 shape=none]
    
    C75 [label = <
        <table cellborder="0" style="rounded">
            <tr><td>C75</td></tr>
            <hr/>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
        </table>
    > margin=0 shape=none]
    
    subgraph cluster_DispenseC100Drink {
        label = "DispenseC100Drink"
        style = rounded
        
        C100 [label = <
            <table cellborder="0" style="rounded">
                <tr><td>C100</td></tr>
                <hr/>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
            </table>
        > margin=0 shape=none]
        
        subgraph cluster_DispenseC125Drink {
            label = "DispenseC125Drink"
            style = rounded
            
            C125 [label = <
                <table cellborder="0" style="rounded">
                    <tr><td>C125</td></tr>
                    <hr/>
                    <tr><td></td></tr>
                </table>
            > margin=0 shape=none]
            
            C150 [label = <
                <table cellborder="0" style="rounded">
                    <tr><td>C150</td></tr>
                    <hr/>
                    <tr><td></td></tr>
                </table>
            > margin=0 shape=none]
    
            C175 [label = <
                <table cellborder="0" style="rounded">
                    <tr><td>C175</td></tr>
                    <hr/>
                    <tr><td></td></tr>
                </table>
            > margin=0 shape=none]
            
            C200 [label = <
                <table cellborder="0" style="rounded">
                    <tr><td>C200</td></tr>
                    <hr/>
                    <tr><td></td></tr>
                </table>
            > margin=0 shape=none]
                }
            }
}

Entry -> C0
C0 -> C25[label=" Add\n$0.25 "]
C0 -> C50[label=" Add\n$0.50 "]

C25 -> C50[label=" Add\n$0.25 "]
C25 -> C75[label=" Add\n$0.50 "]

C50 -> C75[label=" Add\n$0.25 "]
C50 -> C100[label=" Add\n$0.50 "]

C100 -> C0[label=" Dispense\n $1.00 Drink " ltail="cluster_DispenseC100Drink"]

C75 -> C100[label=" Add\n$0.25 "]
C75 -> C125[label=" Add\n$0.50 "]

C100 -> C125[label=" Add\n$0.25 "]
C100 -> C150[label=" Add\n$0.50 "]

C125 -> C150[label=" Add\n$0.25 "]
C125 -> C175[label=" Add\n$0.50 "]

C125 -> C0[label=" Dispense\n $1.25 Drink "  ltail="cluster_DispenseC125Drink"]

C150 -> C175[label=" Add\n$0.25 "]
C150 -> C200[label=" Add\n$0.50 "]

C175 -> C200[label=" Add\n$0.25 "]

C200 -> C0[label=" Dispense\n $2.00 Drink "]

}
```

So, my queries are:

1. How to make this similar to the mentioned image?
2. Is there any other better way to do this apart from my Graphviz code? (Is this the best approach what I have done so far)
3. One transition is missing in Graphviz code that If we pass *Cancel* event, it should go to state *C0* (Please check in attached image). How can we implement this with Graphviz?

Thanks in advance for the suggestions and answers.

Answer (score 2):

"Straight" Graphviz (command line) produces a different (and "closer") result.  Here is you program with just a few tweaks:

```
digraph vendorMachine {
    compound=true
    graph [color=red]
    node [color=red]  // yuck style=filled fillcolor=yellow]
    edge [color=red]
    
    Entry[shape="point" label=""]

    subgraph cluster_cancel {
        label = "Cancel"
        style = rounded

    E2   [shape=rect label="" width=2 style=invis]
    E2:sw->C0  [label=cancel]


        C0 [label = <
            <table cellborder="0" style="rounded">
                <tr><td>C0</td></tr>
                <hr/>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
            </table>
        > margin=0 shape=none]
        
        C25 [label = <
            <table cellborder="0" style="rounded">
                <tr><td>C25</td></tr>
                <hr/>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
            </table>
        > margin=0 shape=none]

        C50 [label = <
            <table cellborder="0" style="rounded">
                <tr><td>C50</td></tr>
                <hr/>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
            </table>
        > margin=0 shape=none]
        
        C75 [label = <
            <table cellborder="0" style="rounded">
                <tr><td>C75</td></tr>
                <hr/>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
            </table>
        > margin=0 shape=none]
        
        subgraph cluster_DispenseC100Drink {
            label = "DispenseC100Drink"
            style = rounded
            
            C100 [label = <
                <table cellborder="0" style="rounded">
                    <tr><td>C100</td></tr>
                    <hr/>
                    <tr><td></td></tr>
                </table>
            > margin=0 shape=none]
            
            subgraph cluster_DispenseC125Drink {
                label = "DispenseC125Drink"
                style = rounded
                
                C125 [label = <
                    <table cellborder="0" style="rounded">
                        <tr><td>C125</td></tr>
                        <hr/>
                        <tr><td></td></tr>
                    </table>
                > margin=0 shape=none]
                
                C150 [label = <
                    <table cellborder="0" style="rounded">
                        <tr><td>C150</td></tr>
                        <hr/>
                        <tr><td></td></tr>
                    </table>
                > margin=0 shape=none]
        
                C175 [label = <
                    <table cellborder="0" style="rounded">
                        <tr><td>C175</td></tr>
                        <hr/>
                        <tr><td></td></tr>
                    </table>
                > margin=0 shape=none]
                
                C200 [label = <
                    <table cellborder="0" style="rounded">
                        <tr><td>C200</td></tr>
                        <hr/>
                        <tr><td></td></tr>
                    </table>
                > margin=0 shape=none]
                    }
                }
    }
    
    Entry -> C0
    C0 -> C25[label=" Add\n$0.25 "]
    C0 -> C50[label=" Add\n$0.50 "]
    
    C25 -> C50[label=" Add\n$0.25 "]
    C25 -> C75[label=" Add\n$0.50 "]
    
    C50 -> C75[label=" Add\n$0.25 "]
    C50 -> C100[label=" Add\n$0.50 "]
    
    C100 -> C0[label=" Dispense\n $1.00 Drink " ltail="cluster_DispenseC100Drink"]
    C75 -> C100[label=" Add\n$0.25 "]
    C75 -> C125[label=" Add\n$0.50 "]
    C100 -> C125[label=" Add\n$0.25 "]
    C100 -> C150[label=" Add\n$0.50 "]
    C125 -> C150[label=" Add\n$0.25 "]
    C125 -> C175[label=" Add\n$0.50 "]
    C125 -> C0[label=" Dispense\n $1.25 Drink "  ltail="cluster_DispenseC125Drink"]
    C150 -> C175[label=" Add\n$0.25 "]
    C150 -> C200[label=" Add\n$0.50 "]
    C175 -> C200[label=" Add\n$0.25 "]
    C200 -> C0[label=" Dispense\n $2.00 Drink "]
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, @sroush. That's strange. However, can you suggest how can we add a separate column for clusters (**Cancel**, **DispenseC100Drink** and **DispenseC125Drink**) like added for others (**C0**, **C25**, etc) as mentioned in the [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH2du.png) image? Thanks for helping out, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Is this close enough?  (done by eyeball)

```
  subgraph cluster_cancel { 
        label = <
            <table cellborder="0" border="0"> 
                <tr><td width="478" >Cancel</td></tr>
                <hr/>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
            </table>
        >
```

Comment: Yes, it is! Thanks. But as we can have multiple subgraphs with different widhts. Is there a way to match the table and hr tag with the outer one exactly and not hard-code the width value?

Comment: try `dot -Tdot`, then use GVPR, python, or the like to calculate the width and edit the file.

Comment: Can you describe this in a bit more detail? I want an SVG image as an output.